# MYSQL query, conditional join if in between two dates

Tags: mysql, join, if-statement

So I have an existing Mysql query that is pretty intense as-is which goes something like:

```
SELECT CURRENT.*, PROGRAMS.NAME 
FROM CURRENT 
LEFT JOIN PROGRAMS ON CURRENT.PID = PROGRAMS.ID 
ORDER BY PID ASC
```

Now, I want to use this query to do something else since I'm already hitting my database.  I have a third table called "TIMEWINDOWS", how would I use this query to return a set of tinyint (0 or 1) based on whether or not it's between the Start_Time and End_Time along with all the other stuff already in my query?

Thanks a lot for the help.

The TimeWindows table has the following stuff:

```
ID               int(11) PK
PID              int(11)   <-- Can join on this from any of the other tables.
ALL_DAY          tinyint(1)
START_DATE       date
END_DATE         date
EARLIEST   time
LATEST     time
NOTICE       int(11)
LATEST  time
MAX int(11)
MIN int(11)
PROBABLE_START   time
PROBABLE_END     time
```

I want to check if it's between start & end date, and return a bool if it is but I can't seem to find a way to do so, can anyone help?

Comment: Which value should be checked if it is between START_DATE and END_DATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CURRENT.*, PROGRAMS.NAME, 
  CASE WHEN t.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BetweenStartEnd
FROM CURRENT 
  LEFT JOIN PROGRAMS ON CURRENT.PID = PROGRAMS.ID 
  LEFT JOIN TIMEWINDOWS t ON (t.PID = CURRENT.PID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') > START_DATE 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') < END_DATE
  )
ORDER BY PID ASC
```

Comment: As a question, how do I use the 0/1 that is being returned by this?

Comment: You wanted to return a boolean, when it is between the dates you get 1 (`true`) and when it's not then you get 0 (`false`). That's because if the `LEFT JOIN` with timewindows does not have a result it returns `NULL` for the `CURRENT.PID`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're lacking some info to give you a code sample, but check out this page, it might help:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if